# Why is the result of two function definitions joined by a comma?

Tags: javascript, return-value, anonymous-function

Why does the following code alert `2`?

```
var f = (function x(){ return 1; }, function y(){ return 2; })();
alert(f);
```

What I can see is that somehow the `y` function is getting executed and `x` function is ignored. (I have made sure that I put `alert` in both functions, and only the `alert` in `y` is called which make me believe that the `x` function is not being called at all)

And if I remove the `y` function then it alerts `1`.

What's going on?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, let's break it down a little.

```
(function x(){ return 1; }, function y(){ return 2; })
```

Is two function literals.Next the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) is used. It evaluates the expressions (both functions) and returns the last one. the result of this expression is: `function y(){ return 2; }`

Which means the remaining expression is: `var f = (function y(){ return 2; })();`

The next thing we do is call it (with the `()`) which returns 2 into the variable `f`;

Comment: Thank you mate, i dont know how to accept 2 answers there should been such an option. so i will upvote you.

Comment: Well, the other answer is also good. To be honest my answer was first by a few minutes, it links to the exact same resource but explains it instead of quoting it, and I think gives a better explanation to the issue, that's just my opinion though.

Comment: I am sorry mate, I have accepted other answer because of only 1 reason and that is on my screen i can see the accepted answer is 2 minutes earlier than yours. So i am not sure what to do, I am confused :(

Comment: They're both good answers, I personally prefer the unaccepted one, since it showed me a detail I'd missed from the first one. However I'm confused as to why you're chosing to mark an answer as correct because it was first, rather than because it was more accurate. Surely a more accurate answer is preferable to an answer that was typed faster?

Comment: @Racheet When the other answer adds a reference to the exact same resource a few minutes later, that's somewhat suspicious to me (not accusing anyone of anything). If the answers were fundamentally different I'd completely agree.

Answer (score 5):

When you use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), the returned value is that of the last element, in your case, the function `y()` (which returns 2)

From the mozilla docs:

> The comma operator evaluates both of its operands (from left to right)
>   and returns the value of the second operand.
>
> You can use the comma operator when you want to include multiple
>   expressions in a location that requires a single expression. The most
>   common usage of this operator is to supply multiple parameters in a
>   for loop.